# How to pinvoke GetExitCodeProcess with negative exit codes?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke

The pinvoke documentation fro GetExitCodeProcess shows exit codes returned as unsigned integers (uint).  How do I handle a process with negative exit code values?  Is LPDWORD correctly assigned to uint or is that a bug in pinvoke doc?

pinvoke doc:
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getexitcodeprocess

win32 api doc:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DWORD` in unsigned integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751.aspx).

> A 32-bit unsigned integer. The range is `0` through `4294967295` decimal.
>
> This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows:
>
> ```
> typedef unsigned long DWORD;
> ```

No bug here.

Comment: bizzare...as a test I created a process that returns a negative exit code.  I created another process to launch the first process, wait for it to exit, and then pinvoke to get exit code.  I changed the pinvoke definition to accept an int instead of a uint and I get back the correct negative exit code.  not sure how to explain that.

Comment: @SFun28 This is explained by [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Comment: More precisely, by the fact that the two numbers (a negative signed and some big positive unsigned) have same binary representation, which is logically treated differently depending on whether or not the value is "known" to be signed/unsigned.